# In-mapper combining and when does cleanup routine of mapper executes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, combiners

I'm trying simple bi-gram (word pair) count, I tried with simple "pair" approach, now I just modified to try "Stripes" approach, but in Cleanup routine of mapper, somehow my all keys are same word pair (as in last word pair!) and counts.

e.g. text input is:

> My name is foo.  Foo is new to Hadoop.

In mapper my hashmap looks like:

```
((my, name), 1), ((name, is), 1), ((is, foo), 2), ((is, new), 1), ((new, to), 1), ((to, hadoop), 1)
```

But in Cleanup routine, I tried to print same hashmap, it looks like

```
((to, hadoop), 1), ((to, hadoop), 1), ((to, hadoop), 2), ((to, hadoop), 1), ((to, hadoop), 1), ((to, hadoop), 1)
```

My code looks like:

```
Map Class:
private HashMap<TextPair, Integer> h = new HashMap<TextPair, Integer>();;

void map(...) :
    ...
StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());            
left = itr.nextToken();
while(itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
right = itr.nextToken();

if(left != null && right!= null) {
            **//I have to create new TextPair(key object) each time!** 
    key.set(new Text(left.toLowerCase()), new Text(right.toLowerCase()));
    //If key is there, just do count + 1 else add key with value 1
    if(h.containsKey(key)) {
            int total = h.get(key) + 1;         
        h.put(key, total);
    } else {
        System.out.println("key: "+ key.toString()+ " => 1");                       
        h.put(key, 1);
    }
            //context.write(key, one);
    }
    left = right;
}
    ....

void cleanup(...):
   Iterator<Entry<TextPair, Integer>> itr = h.entrySet().iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Entry<TextPair, Integer> entry = itr.next();
    TextPair key = entry.getKey();
    int total = entry.getValue().intValue();
    System.out.println("--- MAP CLEANUP ---: key: "+ key.toString() + " => Total: "+ total);

    context.write(key, new IntWritable(total));
}
...
```

Note: TextPair is my custom key class.
Any suggestion?

### EDIT 1:

does cleanup routine of Map, executed at last after all map tasks are done? And hash is kind of "global", something wrong with that or my iterator?

### EDIT 2:

I have to create new TextPair Key object at each iteration in map() before hashing, that's what the issue was .. its solved, but wondering why so? I used hash with Python so many times, its good, no pain, why I need to create new object each time, I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, cleanup() is called after all the records have been fed to the mapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you don't create new key each time, but reuse the one. So you got the same distribution in both cases and the last key in first set is used everywhere in the second set.

Comment: but I wrote code that checks if key doesn't exist then h.put(key, 1)

Comment: Since you may process huge amount of data, so it isn't a good idea to accumulate records in memory. The best way is using Combiner.

Comment: Could you post a full code of map, I still think that you use the same object for all keys.

Comment: you're right, it always takes last key ... I update my key each time, (updating my post), and then do h.put(key, value), ..so if key doesn't exist it should just create, isn't it? And same key then why different records in Hash table? shouldn't it be only 1 with last total as value?

Comment: You should create new TextPair object on each itereation, also you should be ensured that you had implemented 'equals' and 'hashCode' correctly. It were of mutuality problems; you used HashMap incorrectly, so it isn't a surprise that you code worked strange.

Comment: Equals and hashCode is fine, as I mentioned before this works fine with pair approach ... I'm new to Java, may be I used HashMap incorrectly .. and as you said using combiner is best, yes I did, but I read in book "Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce" by Jimmy Lin and Chris Dyer that Strips is best approach, their result shows its faster! so trying! Thanks BTW .. I'll google for HashMap example! :)

Comment: You shouldn't change identity properties of object after it was inserted to any variation of hashtable, like HashMap, it is a source of weird bugs. So YES, `key.set(...)` isn't good enough, because you use the same object, you should create new TextPair on each iteration.

Comment: thanks @rystsov, creating New object solved this issue, but if you can explain why or suggest some pointers I can read, that would be great! Thanks again!

Comment: You can find it javadocs  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the TextPair class example from 'Hadoop: The Definitive Guide'?

The problem is that it isn't safe to use a mutable Object as a key value for a HashMap.
Instead, you should use immutable keys, like the primitives.
Since the TextPair class example from the guide is mutable, problems may arise when putting/getting/removing values through the key objects.

One way to work around this problem is to create a new TextPair Object every time, as you already did.
Another way to solve it, is to use the SimpleImmutableEntry class.

I encountered the same problem you have and solved it by implementing a version with SimpleImmutableEntry's.